# How to execute a PostgreSQL with "WITH" statement?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, dbeaver

I need to execute a query with WITH statement. If I run it, my WITH data shows error. This is my sample query please guide me to execute it.

```
with
x1_fields as
(SELECT
      x1.id as x_id,
      x1.created_time as x_created,
      sum(x1.value) as x_sum

FROM
    xxxx1 x1
    INNER JOIN xxxx2 x2 ON x2.id = x1.id
    INNER JOIN xxxx3 x3 ON x3.id = x2.id
WHERE
     x1.customer = 'microsoft'
GROUP BY
    x1.id,
    x1.created_time
 )
SELECT
  y.id as final_id,
  x_t.sum as final_sum
FROM
    yyyy       as y
    left join x1_fields as x_t on x_t.x_id = y.id
    
where
      y.customer = 'microsoft'
  and y.id = '123456'
```

I have try to run this query in DBeaver but I can't run this. But it works in SSRS. I need to check such queries in some SQL software and debug it. Please give me some instructions to solve this.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: x1_fields doesn't exists. I am unable to execute the query

Comment: Well, `x_t.sum` needs to be `x_t.x_sum` as that is the alias given to the result of the sum. But then the query is syntactically correct and won't result in an error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=758ad685d3a638294f832701ca2e82df I assume that by obfuscating everything you have removed the actual root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know your database and table structure, we cannot find an error which might occure because of wrong relation names or something.

However: Syntax error is the `,` character after the `WITH` clause (before the final `SELECT`). You have to remove it.

Comment: Removed the comma but I am still getting the error like x1_fields not exists

Comment: Can you execute the SELECT inside the WITH clause without problems?

Comment: did execute the query separately both are working good. The query that I mentioned here, it just a sample of a small code. I have a 1989 lines of query which wants to execute in the same format (inside a single query). I need the query in same format to avoid db crash.

Comment: It is quite hard to identify your problem in that case. You me your sample seems to be ok. However, as mentioned, without knowing about your actual table structure, this would be not successful here. Maybe you can try to reproduce your problem in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13 However: 2000 lines of SQL code is never a good sign. You should think about breaking this up, using transactions or your backend. My experience is: In 2 years, no-one is ever able to maintain this query anymore.